# Show explorer context button for specific files, vs code extension development

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have command GenerateLink which works only for images and markdown files:

```json
{
    "command": "extension.GenerateLink",
    "group": "navigation",
    "when":"resourceLangId == markdown"
}
```

However, I don't understand how to set such when condition not for language files, but for images also, and make this condition multiple.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's late but still could be of help for someone.You can match the file name against a regex by using the `=~` operator and make use of `&&` to add multiple conditions:

```json
{
    "when": "resourceLangId == markdown && resourceFilename =~ /my_special_name_[0-9]+\\.png/",
    "command": "extension.GenerateLink",
    "group": "navigation",
}
```